# Loading large amounts of data into a List collection of business objects from Oracle

Tags: c#, xml, linq, oracle

I need a way to optimize the data retrieval of millions of records from an Oracle database into a List of custom business object. The data that is being returned from Oracle is in XML format and I need a way to serialize it into a List of business objects.

The code I wrote is working properly, however, it is taking a long time to execute during the loading of the XML into memory, specifically when the code hits the line:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
```

Code :

```
//Custom Business object  
 public class AccountType
    {
        public int AccountTypeID { get; set; }
        public string AccountCode { get; set; }
        public string BookType { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }

//Code that retrieves data from Oracle DB

  using (OracleConnection objOracleConnection = new OracleConnection(strConnectionString))
            {
                using (OracleCommand orclCmd = objOracleConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    try
                    {

                        orclCmd.CommandText = strXMLSQL;
                        orclCmd.BindByName = true;
                        orclCmd.XmlCommandType = OracleXmlCommandType.Query;
                        orclCmd.XmlQueryProperties.RootTag = "AccountData";
                        orclCmd.XmlQueryProperties.RowTag = "ROW";

                        objOracleConnection.Open();
                        XmlReader xmlReader = orclCmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
                        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);                             
                        List<AccountType> accountTypes = (from data in xDoc.Root.Elements("ROW")
                                                              select new AccountType
                                                              {
                                                                  AccountTypeID = data.GetIntXMLElementValue("ACCOUNTTYPEID"),
                                                                  AccountCode = data.GetStringXMLElementValue("ACCOUNTCODE"),
                                                                  BookType = data.GetStringXMLElementValue("BOOKTYPE"),
                                                                  Status = data.GetIntXMLElementValue("STATUS")
                                                              }).ToList();

                    }
                    catch (OracleException oracleEx)
                    {
                        throw oracleEx;
                    }
                    catch (Exception generalEx)
                    {
                        throw generalEx;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        objOracleConnection.Close();
                    }
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: millions of records to memory? sound weird? why you do that?

Comment: Well, I think technical requirement is more corrective?

Comment: we currently are already using the datareader, which is theoretically the ideal situation, however, we would like to move away from the datareader.

Comment: Why you want to move away datareader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paging is an option. Also threading using PLINQ right before you call the ToList() because that is where you are taking the hit. I would also add that removing the XDocument loading could help. Try deserializing the xml. Assuming your XML looks like this

```
<ROWSET>
    <ROW>
        <AccountData>
            <ACCOUNTTYPEID>1</ACCOUNTTYPEID>
            <ACCOUNTCODE>ABC</ACCOUNTCODE>
            <BOOKTYPE>FOO</BOOKTYPE>
            <STATUS>10</STATUS>
        </AccountData>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <AccountData>
            <ACCOUNTTYPEID>2</ACCOUNTTYPEID>
            <ACCOUNTCODE>XYZ</ACCOUNTCODE>
            <BOOKTYPE>BAR</BOOKTYPE>
            <STATUS>20</STATUS>
        </AccountData>
    </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

You can set up the following contracts:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class AccountData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ACCOUNTTYPEID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "ROW", Namespace = "")]
public class Row
{
    [DataMember(Name = "AccountData")]
    public AccountData Data { get; set; }
}

[CollectionDataContract(Name="ROWSET", Namespace = "")]
public class RowSet
    : List<Row>
{
}
```

and de-serialize like this

```
var s = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(RowSet));
var o = s.ReadObject(xmlreader) as RowSet;
```

This avoides the XDocument loading and LINQ-XML overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the millions of records all at once?

Is the data stored in the database as XML? If not you can use [ExexcutePageReader](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand~ExecutePageReader.html) instead of ExecuteXmlReader

If it has to be XML then you could implement your own pager by calling for records where id is between lastId plus 1 and lastId plus pageLength

Comment: thanks for the response Paul. I need all the records in one shot so I can't use the ExecutePageReader() on the Oracle command object.  I was hoping there would be a faster way to load the data into the list.